# file_get_contents strange issue

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using simple_html_dom ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net ) to parse html code. I've built an application on my local WAMP server, and when everything worked fine, i uploaded it on my internet site, but something was crashing my server (same code as local).
I tracked the problem to this line of the library : 
`$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);`

i tried to make a test file :

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents('http://mysite.net');
var_dump($content);
?>
```

this works fine, however
`$content=file_get_contents('http://mysite.net/gaming/search.php?search_id=active_topics');`

or simply `$content=file_get_contents('http://mysite.net/gaming');`

returns `bool(false)` which means incorrect file

everything works thing on my WAMP server, but on my debian Apache server, i get that.
I thought that maybe my problem comes from my php.ini files, but i don't know where to start (both allow_url_fopen are ON)

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I tried to add `ini_set('display_errors',1);`
and now i get that :
`Warning: file_get_contents(http://mysite.net/gaming): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /web/*******`
could it be because of URL rewriting or something ? (even if it worked on local server x) )

Comment: Why don't you try cURL? Would be easier to set parameters.

Comment: i'm using this fonction because the library i'm using is build with it, but i'll try to modify it with cURL thanks ;)

Comment: Just saw the edit you've made so is there really such responding URL?

Comment: As you can see in my last comment in the post below, this URL is correct on Windows but when using elinks or anything else on debian, it gives me a 404, it doesn't seem to be a php error, more likely some URL rewriting issue. I know the webmaster of this site so maybe i could tell him to correct something but i don't know what yet :/

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the PHP version you are using, test the following code and see which of the statements works.

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

Comment: $ php -v
    PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Oct 12 2012 15:09:56)
    Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

while my WAMP php version is `5.4.3`

i also tried :
    $file = file_get_contents('http://mysite.net/gaming', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    var_dump($file);
and
    $file = file_get_contents('http://mysite.net/gaming', true);
    var_dump($file);

but both returned false :(

Comment: Try locating a file instead of a URL to no file. Ex. gaming/index.php not just gaming.. And if the rewriting is incorrect it results in a 404 error :) Do a test with a folder that is not rewrite-ruled and locate a file there.

Comment: Very strange : with firefox on Windows (local) http://mysite.net/gaming/search.php works fine but with debian : elinks http://mysite.net/gaming/search.php is 404, in fact even http://mysite.net redirects me to the service provider OVH x). Good on windows bad on unix, i don't get it :(

Comment: i think i'm getting close to the real problem : when pinging the domain, mysite.net, i getone IP on Windows and on a local debian server, but when pinging this site from my own server (which is hosted by OVH too :D) i get another address (cluster014.ovh.net).Seems like a DNS issue

Comment: i added an host entry in /etc/hosts with the right IP and the domain name and now, everything works fine ! thanks everyone for your help :)